# LINQ Query to Convert string to datetime

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, datetime

I want to convert the string value to date time

**Class**

```
public class demoDate
{
    public DateTime DueDate;
    public int OrderReportID;

    public DateTime _DueDate 
    { 
        get { return DueDate; } 
        set { DueDate = value; } 
    }

    public int _OrderReportID 
    { 
        get { return OrderReportID; } 
        set { OrderReportID = value;} 
    }
}
```

**Query**

```
var DateQuery = (from o in db.Order_Reports
                 select new demoDate {
                    DueDate = System.DateTime.Parse(o.ReportDueDateTime), 
                    OrderReportID = o.OrderReportID
                 }).ToList();
```

This coding shows following error

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: try use `Convert.ToDateTime` instead

Comment: You'll need to materialize `db.Order_Reports` (e.g. `.ToList()`) before doing the projection, as EF can't parse the convert into a sql expression.

Comment: @Grundy That too shows error LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @StuartLC - I have removed the .ToList() then it shows error at the time of bind grid- LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert string to datetime value in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18567530/convert-string-to-datetime-value-in-linq)

Comment: Not related to your problem, but (a) why do you public fields _and_ properties to access them and (b) why do your property names start with `_` instead of the fields?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to first materialize the query (i.e. load the data) to your application and then parse it. Entity Framework doesn't know how to execute .Net methods (like `DateTime.Parse`), it only knows how to translate them to `SQL`

```
var DateQuery = db.Order_Reports.ToList().Select(o => new demoDate 
{
    DueDate=DateTime.Parse(o.ReportDueDateTime),
    OrderReportID= o.OrderReportID
});
```

Comment: Won't this load the entire table each time it's called? 
That might be A LOT of data if the table is big.

Comment: @RuneAntonsen very true. But unavoidable if you're using regular .Net methods that can't be translated to queries. It would probably be best to redesign this entirely.

Comment: or alternatively you can project your columns, then invoke ToList and then apply another select to create the instance

Answer (score 21):

If you need convert it with SQL you can try use SqlFunctions.DateAdd and just add zero interval.

```
var DateQuery = db.Order_Reports.Select(o => new demoDate {
    DueDate = SqlFunctions.DateAdd("day", 0, o.ReportDueDateTime), 
    OrderReportID = o.OrderReportID
 });
```

Comment: This answer is really clever. It addresses circumstances where the conversion cannot be performed prior to the query while circumventing the need to load the dataset into memory or iterate over the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime myDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTimePicker.Text);

var kayitVarmi = (from myfTable in db.tbl_myfTable 
                              .
                              .
                              .
                              .                      
                              where
                                tbl_donemAyYil.donemAyYilKu == myDateTime
```