# In LINQ Query convert the string to datetime and check with today's date

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, datetime

In Table, DueDate data type is varchar. Now I want to check the due date with today's date

```
 var query = (from o in db.Order_Reports
              where Convert.ToDateTime(o.ReportDueDateTime) >= DateTime.Now
              select o);
```

**The error**

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

How am i suppose to convert the string to date and time and check with today's date

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ Query to Convert string to datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038960/linq-query-to-convert-string-to-datetime)

Comment: It won't work as you describe it... There may possibly be a workaround, however. What is the exact format of ReportDueDateTime column? Is it YYYYMMDD?

Comment: Why are you asking this question again? Was there something you don't like about the answer you accepted? And why is `DueDate` a `varchar` surely that's the problem to fix right there?

Comment: @DarkWanderer - ReportDueDateTime format may be MM/dd/yyyy or M/d/yyyy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a way to implement it as you describe it, because

1. There's no function in SQL that will filter the dates in string format by inequality (at least those that work with your date format and are convertable from LINQ to SQL query).
2. You have a flaw in your database design which prevents "normal" methods from working

However, there are some possible workarounds

1. Amend the database so that the date is of actual datetime format (best option, but of course sometimes unavailable)
2. Create a stored procedure to achieve the same goal. In the SQL code, you can use date parsing
3. Amend the query as follows:

(code)

```
// Our required date
DateTime reportDate = new DateTime(2014,1,1).Date; 
// Let's find number of days between now and required day. Ensure that the date is not in the future!
int deltaDays = (DateTime.Now.Date - date).Days; 
// Let's get the list of dates which we need the reports for
var dates = Enumerable.Range(0, deltaDays + 1).Select(dd => DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-dd).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")).ToArray();
// and query by this list
var query = (from o in db.Order_Reports
          where o.ReportDueDateTime in dates
          select o);
```

This will be a little inefficient, but achieve the purpose without changing the DB. Treat it as temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try DateTime.Parse(o.ReportDueDateTime) and see if that works

Comment: Not working the error - LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: In which case outside the Linq query declare a string variable and set it to DateTime.Now.ToString() then perform a string comparison in the Linq query, bit of a hash but it should work. However you should look at changing the database column to DateTime if possible.

Comment: Fair point - I didnt notice that. This problem does stem from the original design of the database, A column should be of the actual type that you are storing and not stored as a varchar.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Linq-to-Entities is not capable of turning `Convert.ToDateTime` into valid sql. If you bring all the records into memory with a call to `AsEnumerable()` or `ToList()` then you will be using Linq-To-Sql and that will work with C# functions:

```
var query = (from o in db.Order_Reports.AsEnumerable()
              where DateTime.ParseExact(o.ReportDueDateTime, 
                                        "MM/dd/yyyy", 
                                        "M/d/yyyy") >= DateTime.Now
              select o);
```

The problem with that is that you might be bringing too many records into memory. But if you have enough reports for that to be a worry, then you should probably be putting a database index on that `ReportDueDateTime` and you need that index to be in date order. So change that column to a `DateTime` or change the data into a format that can be sorted alphabetically - like "YYYY-MM-DD-HH-mm". Then you could do this:

```
var query = (from o in db.Order_Reports
             where String.Compare(ReportDueDateTime, 
                                  DateTime.Now.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD-HH-mm")) >= 0
              select o);
```

Comment: It shows error like operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of  type 'string' and 'string'

Comment: Try `String.Compare(o.ReportDueDateTime, DateTime.Now
                                                   .ToString("YYYY-MM-DD-HH-mm") >= 0` instead

Comment: Not sure which one you tried but just realised that `Convert.ToDateTime might not work if the culture doesn't match. Edited to use `ParseExact

Answer (score 0):

yes this a problem in Linq-to-Entities 
this case happend when regular DateTime except that it is `nullable`

Linq can understand `Convert.ToDateTime` or `GetValueOrDefault()`

But  Entitie Not sported that

you cane use **Date.Value**
this Code :

```
var x = myContext.MyTable.Where(tbl => tbl .MyDateColumn.Value == DateTime.Now)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use String.Compare.

```
var query = from o in db.Order_Reports
            where String.Compare(o.ReportDueDateTime, Now.ToString()) > 0
            select o;
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will work

```
// Make new variable in DateTime Format
DateTime dateFrom = DateTime.ParseExact(o.ReportDueDateTime, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var query = (from o in db.Order_Reports
              where dateFrom >= DateTime.Now
              select o);
```

Comment: `o.ReportDueDateTime` cannot be referenced outside of the LINQ statement.

Comment: My fault, sorry. I'm used Dynamic LINQ library for similar task.