# Convert Date to Shamsi in linq query

Tags: c#, linq, persian

I want to convert Gregorian date to Shamsi in Linq query

This is my query

```
Contex = new RfidReaderEntities1();
var selectall = from myreads in Contex.V_DriverWithReadTags select new { myreads.RfidTagId, myreads.CarType, myreads.Plate, myreads.VisiteDate, myreads.Lname,myreads.shamsidate}; 
dataGridView1.DataSource = selectall.ToList();
```

I want to convert `myreads.VisiteDate` to Shamsi date.

Comment: Tempted to vote this off-topic: 'I want to sing Gregorian'

Comment: possible duplicate of [In LINQ Query convert the string to datetime and check with today's date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21041296/in-linq-query-convert-the-string-to-datetime-and-check-with-todays-date)

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd: Should we move it to music.stackexchange.com? Seriously, I don't understand what OP wants at all.

Comment: You can use `PersianConverter` to convert Gregorian to Shamsi.

Comment: You can use different calendars through the [System.Globalization.Calendar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class and its derived classes, eg. [PersianCalendar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.persiancalendar(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I want to use a  C# function in Query

Comment: shmsidate(myreads.VisiteDate)

Comment: Excuse me if I can tell a good concept

Comment: I want use a C# function inside a query

Comment: I want use a C# function inside a query

Comment: var selectall = from myreads in Contex.V_DriverWithReadTags select new { myreads.RfidTagId, myreads.CarType, myreads.Plate,  myfunctionC(myreads.VisiteDate), myreads.Lname,myreads.shamsidate};

Comment: myfunctionC in query

Comment: yes shmsidate(myreads.VisiteDate)

Comment: Using Persia.Net Core can be of help to you. If you are not using .NET Core you can install the oldest version of this library.
https://github.com/shahabfar/Persia-.NET-Core

Answer (score 0):

First download `FarsiLibrary.Utils` because it convert Gregorian to Shamsi without any mistake add it's `DLL` files to your project to more information go [Here](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Farsi.Library).

then try this:

```
var selectall = from myreads in Contex.V_DriverWithReadTags select new {
            RfidTagId = myreads.RfidTagId,
            CarType = myreads.CarType, 
            Plate = myreads.Plate,
            VisiteDate = PersianDateConverter.ToPersianDate(myreads.VisiteDate), 
            Lname = myreads.Lname,
            shamsidate = myreads.shamsidate
        };
```

Comment: Thank you
But it does not show any data in datagridview

Comment: @JavidJavidi Did you download that library ? Did you set your DataGridView's DataSource property ?

Comment: Thank you  yes   download that library and set  DataSource

Answer (score 0):

```
 Contex = new RfidReaderEntities1();


            var selectall = from myreads in Contex.V_DriverWithReadTags select new {
            RfidTagId = myreads.RfidTagId,
            CarType = myreads.CarType, 
            Plate = myreads.Plate,
            VisiteDate = PersianDateConverter.ToPersianDate((DateTime)myreads.VisiteDate), 
           // VisiteDate = myshamsifun.GetShamsiDateTime((DateTime)myreads.VisiteDate), 
            Lname = myreads.Lname,   
        };


            dataGridViewlisttoday.DataSource = selectall.ToList();
```

Comment: What is the difference between this and my answer, it just copy and pasted.

Comment: @soheylaabbb hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii test

Comment: What does that mean ?