# LINQ to entites does not recognize Convert.ToDatetime method

Tags: c#, linq

*EDIT* All the other answers that link to a previous question's wont work for me because they are either using two tables or they know what startdate they are looking for.

I have the following LINQ query where i am trying to get the data from a table for the last 14 days. LINQ does not recognize Convert.ToDatetime method. The Query_Date column is a type string and i can't change it. How do i get the data i need?

```
       var logs = (from bwl in db.UserActivities
       where Convert.ToDateTime(bwl.Query_Date) >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14)                               
                          select new
                          {
                              Id = bwl.Id,
                              UserEmail = bwl.UserEmail                                 

                          }).ToList();
```

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21041296/in-linq-query-convert-the-string-to-datetime-and-check-with-todays-date

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740693/big-issue-in-converting-string-to-datetime-using-linq-to-entities

Comment: What is the DataType of `bwl.Query_Date`?

Comment: The SqlFunctions class could help you out with this as Entity Framework does not support this kind of behavior. Personally I would use the right data types right away instead of converting values in your query.

Comment: @Hari Prasad its a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i couldn't get what i wanted because i would have to make too many changes so the workaround i am doing is: I am using this code

```
var logs = db.UserActivities.ToList().Take(100);
```

This will get me the last 100 entries. I will give options for more or less entries then they can filter it on date in the search bar on the datatable.

It's not great but time is against me and this will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have data being entered at least every day? If so, what about something like this:

```
var oldestDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14); 
var dateString = oldestDate.ToString(*/ your date format */);
var oldestID = db.UserActivities.First(b => b.Query_Date == dateString).Id;
var logs = (from bwl in db.UserActivities
            where bwl.Id > oldestID
            select new {
                Id = bwl.Id,
                UserEmail = bwl.UserEmail
            }).ToList();
```

Basically you find a record on that date and use its ID as a proxy for the date. This only works in certain circumstances (i.e. if the IDs are in date order).

This also isn't guaranteed to be the oldest entry on that date, but that could be achieved either by using ID order:

```
var oldestID = db.UserActivities.Where(b => b.Query_Date == dateString)
                                .OrderBy(b => b.Id)
                                .First().Id;
```

Or more lazily by using -15 instead of -14 when you add days, if you don't mind grabbing an unknown percentage of that 15th day.

Answer (score -1):

`Convert.ToDateTime` works if your `Query_Date` has proper format. If not, check your string expression is convertable format.

I tested below code and it works fine when I assume `Query_Date` is a form of `DateTime.toString()`.

```
var logs = (from bwl in db.UserActivities
        where DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(bwl.Query_Date) <= TimeSpan.FromDays(14)
        select new
        {
            Id = bwl.Id,
            UserEmail = bwl.UserEmail
        }).ToList();
```

I also tested with your *where* expression `Convert.ToDateTime(bwl.Query_Date) >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14)` and confirmed that it gives same result.

Comment: my format in the table is dd/MM/yyyy. i still get LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. no matter what format i put it into

Comment: @user6295447 // could you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2556050/361100 call `ToList()` first in order to pour into memory first. It's not efficient but seems the only option unless your time bits are not meaningful themselves.

Comment: The reason i want the last 2 weeks is that the table holds six months of data and i don't want to be bringing back all the data then displaying the last 2 weeks. I just want to bring back the required data. I will leave it for now and come back to it later when i have more time. I may have to make a few changes to get what im looking for

Comment: @user6295447 // if `id` (or some another) value is guaranteed to increase in sequential order, it could not require all data to be fetched _hopefully_. Of course an iteration job could parse given date and fetch some part of it. whatever, it's not neat :(