# can't convert a string to DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have problem converting a string to DateTime,this is the error

[image]

I have used the solution showed in this link [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038960/linq-query-to-convert-string-to-datetime) and using DateTime.Parse,but I get this error all the time

this is my class Schedule:

```
 public partial class Schedule : BaseEntity
    {

        public string Day { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }
        public DateTime Begin { get; set; }
        public DateTime End { get; set; }

     }
```

any help please and thanks
Update:this is teh query

```
var Schedules = new List<Schedule>
{
    new Schedule
    { 
        Day="Lundi", Note="note", Begin=Convert.ToDateTime("2013-04-24 17:47:03"), 
        End=Convert.ToDateTime("2013-05-24 17:47:03"),
        ClassId = context.Classes.Where(c=>c.Libel=="Class 1").FirstOrDefault().Id, 
        SubjectLevelId = context.SubjectLevels.Where(cbv=>cbv.Coef==1).FirstOrDefault().Id, 
        ClassRoomId = context.ClassRooms.Where(c=>c.Libel=="ClassRoom1").FirstOrDefault().Id, 
        TeacherId = context.Teachers.Where(c=>c.FirstName=="mouna").FirstOrDefault().Id, 
        SchoolYearId=  context.SchoolYears.Where(f=>f.Begin==DateTime.Parse("15/09/2015")).FirstOrDefault().Id
    },
};
Schedules.ForEach(s =>
{
    s.ObjectState = Repository.Pattern.Infrastructure.ObjectState.Added;
    context.Schedules.Add(s);
    context.SaveChanges();
});
```

Comment: Please include the query, not just a screenshot of it. Almost definitely the error is in the part that's been cut off. Your query has nothing to do with `Linq to Entities`, from what's shown, unless there's code in `BaseEntity`'s constructor.

Comment: I have updated my post Sir :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to something like this:

```
var beginDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime("2013-04-24 17:47:03");
var endDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime("2013-05-24 17:47:03");
var schoolYearBeginDate = DateTime.Parse("15/09/2015");
var Schedules = new List<Schedule>
{
    new Schedule
    { 
        Day="Lundi", 
        Note="note", 
        Begin = beginDateTime, 
        End=endDateTime,
        ClassId = context.Classes.Where(c=>c.Libel=="Class 1").FirstOrDefault().Id, 
        SubjectLevelId = context.SubjectLevels.Where(cbv=>cbv.Coef==1).FirstOrDefault().Id, 
        ClassRoomId = context.ClassRooms.Where(c=>c.Libel=="ClassRoom1").FirstOrDefault().Id, 
        TeacherId = context.Teachers.Where(c=>c.FirstName=="mouna").FirstOrDefault().Id, 
        SchoolYearId=  context.SchoolYears.Where(f=>f.Begin==schoolYearBeginDate).FirstOrDefault().Id
    },
};
```

Also, these will eventually throw a null reference exception:

```
context.Classes.Where(c=>c.Libel=="Class 1").FirstOrDefault().Id
```

Change them to:

```
context.Classes.Where(c=>c.Libel=="Class 1").Select(c => c.Id).FirstOrDefault()
```

If `ClassId` etc are *not* nullable, then you should do this:

```
context.Classes.Where(c=>c.Libel=="Class 1").First().Id
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [`AsEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb335435(v=vs.100).aspx) in LINQ query and [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) method

```
Begin = DateTime.ParseExact("2013-04-24 17:47:03", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

`ParseExact` will serve your purpose if you have specific date provided to this function, like shown below. And here is [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation about this method.

```
Begin = DateTime.ParseExact("2013-04-24 17:47:03", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

However `ParseExact` fails if you are providing date from some incoming text box or from other control, and date is absent there then it will throw a runtime error. To avoid that, best is to use `TryParseExact`. Read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx) from MSDN about TryParseExact.

```
Datetime dateTime;
bool isValid = DateTime.TryParseExact("2013-04-24 17:47:03", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime);
```

`isValid` will tell you if conversion was successful and `dateTime` will have your new converted date from string.