# Linq order by issue

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to order a result set by a `VARCHAR2` field that contains date time values. They are obtained from GoToWebinar like this and I can't convert them to `DateTime`:

```
9/29/2016 6:00:00 PM
8/31/16 5:48 PM
9/28/16 5:58 PM
9/14/16 5:57 PM
9/1/16 5:57 PM
9/21/16 5:52 PM
9/22/16 5:59 PM
9/15/16 5:59 PM
9/7/16 5:56 PM
9/8/16 5:55 PM
```

I need them sorted correctly like this:

```
8/31/16 5:48 PM
9/1/16 5:57 PM
9/7/16 5:56 PM
9/8/16 5:55 PM
9/14/16 5:57 PM
9/15/16 5:59 PM
9/21/16 5:52 PM
9/22/16 5:59 PM
9/28/16 5:58 PM
9/29/2016 6:00:00 PM
```

In trying to do this:

```
using (webinarAttendeesListDbContext context = new webinarAttendeesListDbContext(connectionString))
{
    System.Linq.IQueryable<WebinarAttendeesList> result = null;
        result = from w in context.WebinarAttendeesList
                 where webinarkeys.Contains(w.webinarKey) && w.AttendedWebinar > 0
                 orderby w.PID, DateTime.Parse(w.JoinTime)
                 select w;
    r = result.ToList();
}
```

I get this error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime
>   Parse(System.String)' method,  and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression.

How do I need to do this order by?

Comment: Stop storing dates as text? :) Or just order after you've got the data back...

Comment: We just store them how we get them from GoToWebinar, no conversion. How would I sort them after I got the list using Linq?

Comment: Again, stop storing them like that, and store them in a more sensible field type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `ToList()` to retrieve the data and then order it:

   ```
   using (webinarAttendeesListDbContext context = new webinarAttendeesListDbContext(connectionString))
   {
       var result = (from w in context.WebinarAttendeesList
                     where webinarkeys.Contains(w.webinarKey) && w.AttendedWebinar > 0
                     select w).ToList()
                              .OrderBy(w => w.PID)
                              .ThenBy(w => DateTime.Parse(w.JoinTime));
   }
   ```
2. Another option is to use the [`DbFunctions.CreateDateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.createdatetime(v=vs.113).aspx)
   function.
3. You can also use `SqlFunctions.DateAdd` like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33443127/6400526)

Comment: Same error using this code.

Comment: This will not work. You have to call ToList() so the query gets executed, before calling OrderBy()

Comment: @CristiPufu - True :) copy past mistake

Comment: @MB34 - corrected

Comment: Yep, that fixed the issue and worked like a charm, thanks also for not admonishing me for not storing this data as datetime.

Comment: @Gilad Green, no, they are IDs for the attendee.

Comment: @MB34 - I do think it is wrong to have the data as a string but.... As you said in the comments that is how you got it. I would suggest that you edit the question and write that in the first line of the question

Comment: @RubbleFord - Thanks for the correction

Comment: Yeah, I guess that is why the question Nazis down voted the question.

Comment: @MB34 - It is an important part to mention... :)

Comment: @MB34 You got **one** downvote. That's hardly the "wrath of Meta". And regardless of how you received the data, you still have the ability to change how it is stored in your database. That's _your_ decision that is making your life harder.

Comment: It shouldn't matter WHY it is stored that way, just that it is. Suppose this was legacy data from a long time ago that I had no idea when or why it was stored?

Comment: @MB34 - check update - found another way :)