# LINQ - Convert String to Datetime

Tags: c#, linq

as follow my problem:

I have a table with all nvarchar columns and I would like to load only the records from the current day, like below:

```
 var query = from item in dataContext.Items
             orderby item.CDATE_IUD descending
             where item.QV_USER == user
             where item.QV_EXT == ext
             where item.ACTIVE == 1
             where DbFunctions.DiffDays(Convert.ToDateTime(item.CDATE_IUD), DateTime.Now.Date) == 0
             select item;
```

I get an error that ToDateTime is not recognized in LINQ.

My desired output:

- Load only the current day records

Input:

- item.CDATE_IUD is a string and has the following format dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss (e.g. 20.07.2015 16:12:48)

Any help would be appreciated.

Update:

This works for me:

```
 string today = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
 var query = from item in dataContext.Items
             orderby item.CDATE_IUD descending
             where item.QV_USER == user
             where item.QV_EXT == ext
             where item.ACTIVE == 1
             where item.CDATE_IUD.Substring(0,10) == today
             select item;
```

Comment: Have you tried `DateTime.Parse(...)` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to datetime value in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18567530/convert-string-to-datetime-value-in-linq)

Comment: You should mention that you're using EF or Linq to SQL, as it appears you are. There are a lot of things you can do in C# to do this, but, since you're using LINQ to SQL or EF, that will actually make things somewhat more awkward and should be noted in the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming `item.CDATE_IUD` is a string representation of a date.

Linq to EF and Linq to SQL do not support string to date conversions.  You *can* do the conversion in memory, but since you're *filtering* on the parsed value, then you're pulling in ALL records.  You might be able to use a string comparison instead:

```
string today = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd"); // or whatever format your DB string is on.
var query = from item in dataContext.Items
                        orderby item.CDATE_IUD descending
                        where item.QV_USER == user
                        where item.QV_EXT == ext
                        where item.ACTIVE == 1
                        where item.CDATE_IUD.StartsWith(today)
                        select item;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
DateTime.ParseExact(x, "yyyyMMdd",cultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

will help to convert a string in dateTime

Comment: @CraigW. it will convert server-side expressions too

Comment: Then why when I tried it did I get `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ParseExact(System.String, System.String, System.IFormatProvider)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`