# how to convert MM/dd/YYYY hh:mm:ss AM to YYYY-MM-dd datetime format by linq?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, date, datetime

i have a data from database which includes some columns. one of them is ExpiryDate. it has SAP datetime format : MM/dd/YYYY nn:mm:ss AM

[image]

i wanna convert it from MM/dd/YYYY hh:mm:ss AM to YYYY-MM-dd . Is it possible?

```
   deliveriesItemsbypaging.Convert(q => q.ExpiryDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")).Tolist() <DeliveryItem>;
```

is it possible by using linq?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18567530/convert-string-to-datetime-value-in-linq

Comment: If it's a datetime column it does not store display format.

Comment: You don't need to convert.  Just change format of how data is displayed.  How are you displaying the DataTime.

Comment: this code is not working.                                                                         var query = deliveriesItemsbypaging.Select(tb => tb.ExpiryDate)
                  .AsEnumerable() // Do the rest of the processing locally
                  .Select(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x, "yyyy-MM-dd",
                                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

Comment: @jdweng; can you nmake a sample...

Comment: You're using the 'dataset vizualuser' to view dates. It decides what format a date is. If you don't like it, convert to a string and format it.

Comment: Don't change the `DateTime` values in the object as you are doing, only change it during the representation

Comment: You can't parse a DataTime to a DateTime. it must be a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i have a data from database which includes some columns. one of them is ExpiryDate. it has SAP datetime format : MM/dd/YYYY nn:mm:ss AM

As per my understanding from the question, you are using the SAP for data storage, therefore you must be using a provider available for C# from SAP to connect and fetch the data. Now the important point that needs to be answered is:

1. In C# do you have a `DateTime type` or some `SAP DateTime type`, which stores DateTime, with inherent ability to translate into C# DateTime, my assumption is its the C# DateTime and you want it to be represented in the format - `YYYY-MM-DD`

Now review the DateTime source code as available from Microsoft [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,df6b1eba7461813b)

As it would be clear that there's no constructor which takes the DateTime format anywhere it just fills the internal properties, to know the year, month and date and other relevant values, so no format requirement, mostly during the representation, we call `ToString method` on a DateTime object, where same object can be made to represent appropriate formats, check the following [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) to understand available custom formats.

However when we are converting a `String` to `DateTime`, then in Parse method, there's an option for `IFormatProvider` object, which can take a `DateTimeFormatInfo` object in `System.Globalization` namespace, which can be used for applying the custom / local formats, check source code [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeformatinfo.cs), it can help in achieving much more complex requirements.

Formatting is for the representation purpose, which can done while showing up the value in Ui, Linq has nothing to do with it. You can directly convert the DateTime value in your code with or without Linq, using something like (tested code)

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;  
var dateValue = d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Please note the small caps for year and date and large caps for Month, which is the formatting requirement for the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

if ExpiryDate is a DateTime field you can try

List newDateFormat= deliveriesItemsbypaging.Select(q => q.ExpiryDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")).Tolist()