# How can i convert Char to Datetime in Linq Where clause

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I need help convert char type to dateTime and make a comparison.

I have the [MonthYYYYMM] in a Cost Table as a char type

```
 [MonthYYYYMM] [char](8) NOT NULL,
```

I tried this Linq expression looks like this but doesnt work

```
var ProjectList =  Context.Project.AsNoTracking()                                                   
                     .Include(c=> c.Cost)                                                    
                     .Where(p => p.Cost.Any(c=> DateTime.ParseExact(c.MonthYYYYMM, "yyyyMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) <= request.ToDate
                                               && DateTime.ParseExact(c.MonthYYYYMM, "yyyyMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) >= request.FromDate)                                                
                     .ToListAsync();
```

I get this error

```
> Error Content: System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression
> 'DbSet<Cost>
>     .Where(c => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>((EntityShaperExpression: 
>         EntityType: Project
>         ValueBufferExpression: 
>             (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
>         IsNullable: False
>     ), "ID") != null && EF.Property<Nullable<int>>((EntityShaperExpression: 
>         EntityType: Project
>         ValueBufferExpression: 
>             (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
>         IsNullable: False
>     ), "ID") == EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(c, "ProjectID"))
>     .Any(c => DateTime.ParseExact(
>         s: c.MonthYYYYMM
>         format: "yyyyMM", 
>         provider: __InvariantCulture_0) <= __request_ToDate_1 && DateTime.ParseExact(
>         s: c.MonthYYYYMM
>         format: "yyyyMM", 
>         provider: __InvariantCulture_0) >= __request_FromDate_2)' could not be translated.
```

How can i convert string to date and make the comparison?

Comment: Query the DB and return a `char[]`, and then call `.ToList()` before performing a select to turn the `char[]` into a `string` and then into a `DateTime`.

Comment: thanks @Enigmativity can you give me an example?

Comment: This kind of thing: `Context.Table.Select(x => x.fieldThatIsCharArray).ToList().Select(x => new string(x)).Select(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x, "yyyyMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToList()`

Comment: "I have the [MonthYYYYMM] in a Cost Table as a char type" **There's your problem right  there**. Even if you only need the month and year and not an exact date, it's still better to store it as a `Date` data type.

Comment: Convert `request.ToDate` and `request.FromDate` values on the client to string `yyyyMM` format. Then in query do `Any(c=> c <= toDate && c >= fromDate)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert `request.ToDate` and `request.FromDate` values to the string.

```
string toDate = request.ToDate.ToString("yyyyMM");
string fromDate = request.FromDate.Tostring("yyyyMM");
```

Then use them in the query like this.

```
    .Where(p => p.Cost.Any(c=> 
        c.CompareTo(toDate) <= 0 && c.CompareTo(fromDate) >= 0))
```

Comment: It will show error Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'.

Comment: @MichelleWang - I'm sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.ParseExact(x, "yyyyMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` could not be translated. It isn't possible to use methods inside a `Where` of an `IQueryable`, because `Linq` to `SQL` cannot know how to translate your method into SQL.
You could use `AsEnumerable()` to materialize all your types.

```
var CostList = Context.Cost.AsEnumerable().Where(c => 
             DateTime.ParseExact(c.MonthYYYYMM, "yyyyMM",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) <= ToDate 
           && DateTime.ParseExact(c.MonthYYYYMM, "yyyyMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) >= FromDate);

return Json(CostList);
```

> Test of Result:

[image]

Comment: Using 'AsEnumerable()' to call a method in the where clause of a LINQ query.

Comment: This will pull the entire table from the database to the client. And there could be millions of records.

Comment: Yes, like you said,  that's up to the size of table. It's not recommended if your table is larger.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises because LINQ called on IQueryable (DbSet also implements IQueryable) is translated to SQL in runtime. I think this data conversions cannot be translated at all. So you have two options:

- Change your database to store dates (so You do not need to convert data)
- Do this conversions without translating (e.g. user [AsEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.asenumerable?view=netcore-3.1) method)

Also there is similar question: [Convert string to datetime value in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18567530/convert-string-to-datetime-value-in-linq)

Comment: This is not applicable in this case. Because it is used inside `Any`, inside `Where`.